# Install gdm3 - 3.28.2-2ubuntu1 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gdm

I'm trying to fix this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137?comments=all

In this feed, it says it is fixed in gdm3, version 3.28.2-2ubuntu1 . But I cant update to that version.

```
barney@pterodactyl:~$ sudo apt-get install gdm3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gdm3 is already the newest version (3.28.0-0ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

This is after updating packages. 
Help would be much appreciated because the bug is really annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Version `3.28.2-2ubuntu1` is in Cosmic. A fixed version for Bionic has not yet been released.

A *tentative* fix (`3.28.2-0ubuntu1.2`) is now in `bionic-proposed`; install at your own risk